# Compilation errors after importing the musixtex package

Tags: music, musixtex

I have a problem with my LaTeX project. After I import the musixtex package, I'm suddenly getting compilation errors regarding bibliography, something that I don't think is relevant to the musixtex package. I have created a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, alldates=iso]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{musixtex}
\addbibresource{MyB.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\cite{testsource}.
\printbibliography[title={Literatura}, heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

MyB.bib file:

```
@online{testsource,
  title = {TestSource},
  urldate = {2021-04-03},
  url = {https://stackoverflow.com/},
}
```

So after I import the musixtex package, I get 4 errors regarding the bibliography, two are "Missing number, treated as zero" and two are "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)". The document itself seems to be unaffected, but I'd rather there weren't any compilation errors. If I remove the musixtex package, the problem disappears. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: diploma.cls is an unknown class.

Comment: I didn't realize that, but I replaced it with the article class and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

musixtex redefines the \addspace command from biblatex, and biblatex doesn't like this.

In your example you can reset \addspace before the bibliography, but if it is also used in citations it is probably better to do it the other way round and to reset it before every music piece.

```
\documentclass[czech,bachelor]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,czech=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=iso-numeric, alldates=iso]{biblatex}
\let\biblatexaddspace\addspace
\usepackage{musixtex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\cite{doody}.
\let\addspace\biblatexaddspace
\printbibliography[title={Literatura}, heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This entirely solved my issue, I'm getting no compilation errors whatsoever. Thank you very much for your help.